# Display table results in reverse order in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table

I have the following code in my app that creates a table:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <td>
        <%= link_to (comment.body), comment.pin %>
        </td>

        <td>
        <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</br>
        </td>

        <td>
        <%= link_to (comment.pin.user.name), comment.pin.user %>
        </td>

        <td>
        <%= comment.pin.album %>
        </td>

        <td>
        <%= comment.pin.artist %>
        </td>
```

This is my comments controller:

```
def create
@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
@comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

It works great, except it adds each new comment to the bottom of the table. How can I display it in reverse order, so that the newest comment shows up first? Also, how could I limit it to the 50 most recent comments?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that in your controller action you are doing something like this:

```
@comments = @post.comments
```

That would load all of the posts in the default order (or random, depending on the database). Tweak the above to something like this:

```
@comments = @post.comments.order('created_at DESC').limit(50)
```

You could also create scopes for the order and limit to DRY things up.

Comment: I added my controller info above. I don't want to change the functionality throughout the app, just to list the comments in this table on it's own page in the opposite order that they appear from the code above.

Comment: I got it: comments.reverse.each do